# Show that if $G_{1}$ is a subgroup of $G$, there may be no subgroup of $G_{2}$ of $G$ such that $G=G_{1}\oplus G_{2}$.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, direct-sum

This question is Munkres' book Section 67 Exercise 2:

> Show that if $G_{1}$ is a subgroup of $G$, there may be no subgroup of $G_{2}$ of $G$ such that $G=G_{1}\oplus G_{2}$. (Hint: Set $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $G_{1}=2\mathbb{Z}$)

I have some attempts but I don't know how to proceed:

We set $G:=\mathbb{Z}$ and $G_{1}:=2\mathbb{Z}$ as suggested. Suppose there is a subgroup $G_{2}$ of $G$ such that $G=G_{1}\oplus G_{2}$. Then we know that $G/G_{2}\cong G_{1}$, which implies that $G_{2}$ contains some odd number $z$, since $G_{1}=2\mathbb{Z}$.

What should I do next to derive a contradiction?

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than consider $G/G_2\cong G_1$, think of $G/G_1\cong G_2$.  What does that tell you about the order of $G_2$.

Comment: In any case, there are examples that are perhaps easier. For example, how many subgroups of order $2$ are there in a cyclic group of order $4$?

Comment: @verret then we have $G/G_{1}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, so $G_{2}$ has order of $2$.

Comment: Right, now does $G$ have any subgroup of order $2$?

Comment: @verret no since every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$, which is infinite cyclic.

Comment: @verret thanks! Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: The non-abelian group of order $6$ is another example since the direct sum of abelian (cyclic) groups is abelian. Also note that both components in a direct sum of two groups are normal in the sum. The properties of the direct sum can seem rather trivial, but they have wide-ranging consequences and can be useful for spotting counter-examples.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\Bbb Z=2\Bbb Z\oplus H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $\Bbb Z$. Then, for every $n\in \Bbb Z$ we have **unique** $k\in \Bbb Z$ and **unique** $h\in H$ such that, $n=2\cdot k+h$. Hence, for any element $h\in H$ we have, $2\cdot h+0=2h=2\cdot 0+2h$. Using **uniqueness** we have, $h=0$. That's $H$ is trivial group. $H$ is trivial means $\Bbb Z=2\Bbb Z\oplus\{0\}$, that is each element of $\Bbb Z$ is in $2\Bbb Z$, which is impossible as not all element of $\Bbb Z$ is even.

Comment: Why cannot $H$ be trivial? It is still a subgroup, right?

Comment: I have shown each element of $H$ is zero.

Comment: Yes. Then you conclude that $H$ is trivial and you said this is a contraction? What does it contradict to?

Comment: $H$ is trivial means $\Bbb Z=2\Bbb Z\oplus\{0\}$, that is each element of $\Bbb Z$ is in $2\Bbb Z$, which is impossible as not all element is even number.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Is it okay to you now?

Comment: Oh! Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an easier example is $G = \mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2,3\}$, with subgroup $H = 2\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z} = \{0,2\}$.

But none of $\{0,1\}$,$\{0,3\}$ or $\{0,1,3\}$ form a subgroup, so there is no subgroup which intersects $H$ trivially, so no subgroup which is a complementary direct summand to $H$ in $G$.